# How to get custom claims in access token not id token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, bearer-token, azure-identity, azure-app-registration

In my application, I created few attributes and added those custom attributes in optional claims section selecting both access token and id token.

In Manifest file of application, claims added to both types: access token and id token. But the generated access token didn't have added custom attributes. I can see those in id token but my requirement is to get custom attributes in both access token and id token.

What am I missing? Any way to achieve this?